# Date Input not being set on selecting a date

Tags: angularjs, date, input

I am trying to create a function that automatically calculates a person's age based on a selected date of birth.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
      <label class="control-label">DOB</label>
      <date-input name="{{member.MemberID + 'Birthdate'}}" max="controller.today" ng-model="member.NoServicesProvided.birthDate" ng-change="controller.calcAge(member)"></date-input>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-class="{'has-error': noServicesProvidedForm[member.MemberID + 'Age'].$invalid && noServicesProvidedForm.rootFormSubmitted()}">
      <label class="control-label">Age</label>
      <input name="{{member.MemberID + 'Age'}}" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="member.NoServicesProvided.age" required valid-number>
</div>
```

```
function calcAge(member) {
     if(member.NoServicesProvided.birthDate) {
           var deltaDate = Date.now() - member.NoServicesProvided.birthDate.getTime();
           var ageDate = new Date(deltaDate);
           member.NoServicesProvided.age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
           console.log(member.NoServicesProvided.age);
     } 
}
```

The problem comes when entering a date for the first time. When I select a date, for some reason it says member.NoServicesProvided is undefined. This NoServicesProvided property is being used elsewhere on the page with no issue. Then, when I select another date, it suddenly works but with the first date entered rather than the second.

Is there something I'm missing? Please know that I need to keep it in this kind of format. Any help is appreciated though!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Inside the calcAge function, wrap the code inside a $timeout( function() { ... } );